# Edit did not correct critical issues with the post - I disagree

Tags: support

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/42296

This edit just got rejected. The 'Community' user cited a strange reason, which I think doesn't apply:

> This edit did not correct critical issues with the post - view the revision history to see what should have been changed

The user who rejected and edited just changed all 'Time Sheet's to 'timesheet's.

I don't understand what's happening here. My edit was more substantial than that.

Comment: I've resubmitted the edit - feel free to review: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/42297

Comment: The latter edit has since been approved.

Comment: I also don't know what it means that Community, rather than a user or group of users, reviewed an edit.  I think I've had that question before (somewhere on the network) but I don't remember the answer. :-(

Comment: @MonicaCellio it means that a (human) reviewer has picked an option "Reject and Edit", see [Why does the Community ♦ user approve and reject edits?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184992/165773) FWIW as a moderator you can suspend users from reviewing edits for a while if you feel like their approach needs correction

Comment: @gnat OK, so it was because the other guy picked 'Reject and Edit'? Makes sense - the community user marks it as rejected, and at the same time the other user can edit the post. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @gnat thanks.  So there were really only two reviewers, but Community did the bidding of one of them, generating a separate entry.  Yeah, that's confusing -- the "(user) Reject and Edit" entry should be enough.